# grecaptcha.getResponse(); returns empty line

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, grecaptcha

I am trying to implement google recaptcha v2 using ajax php but its not returning response after i solve it. i have two recaptchas, with different keys, first one works just fine.

after solving recaptcha:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEA0X.png)

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>


 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "contact.php",
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                subject: subject,
                message: message,
                captcha: grecaptcha.getResponse()
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
            if (!parsedResponse.success) {
                $('#response').text(parsedResponse.message);
                $('#contact_form_2')[0].reset();
            } else {
                $('#response').text("Wiadomość została wysłana.");
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#response').text('Wystąpił błąd podczas wysyłania wiadomości.');
        });
```

```
 $recaptcha_secret = 'key';
    $rresponse=$_POST["captcha"];

$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_data = array(
    'secret' => $recaptcha_secret,
    'response' => $rresponse
);

$recaptcha_options = array(
    'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'content' => http_build_query($recaptcha_data)
    )
);

$recaptcha_context = stream_context_create($recaptcha_options);
$recaptcha_result = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url, false, $recaptcha_context);
$recaptcha_json = json_decode($recaptcha_result);

if (!$recaptcha_json->success) {
    $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Potwierdzenie reCAPTCHA nie powiodło się.');
    echo json_encode($response);
    return;
}
```

i was changing the code a lot, to the moment where captcha was working but it was redirecting to contact.php and not returing result to response as supposed. im in dead end

Comment: Is that all the PHP code? If so, you don't seem to actually output anything at all if `$recaptcha_json->success` is true, which would ofc result in an empty response.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I don't think they are talking about `response` in the AJAX success callback, but the result of calling `grecaptcha.getResponse()`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api: _"`grecaptcha.getResponse( opt_widget_id )` - Gets the response for the reCAPTCHA widget. `opt_widget_id` - Optional widget ID, **defaults to the first widget created if unspecified.**"_ - so you will have to specify the widget ID in your call there, otherwise it will try to fetch the response from the _first_ CAPTCHA on the page - which will of course be blank, when you filled out only the _second_ one.